# How come Goku was defeated by Frost of the 6th Universe?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super

Can anyone explain the reason why Frost of the 6th Universe was able to disable or paralyze Goku? I didn't get how that was possible!

Is there any sort of cheating or is there any ability of Frost that can paralyze the opponent somehow?

By the way, I am talking about Dragon Ball Super, episode 33.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its been revealed in ep. 34 that frost contains a needle within his wrist that allows him to poison his opponents. This is how he defeated Goku .

Comment: Is it considered cheating?

Comment: Yes but meanwhile rather than disqualifying him Vegeta offered to crush him. Note: I've kept a little out to avoid ruining the series.

Comment: Aw come on, it's going to be *years* before it gets on TV. Ruin away!

Comment: @axelrod The Manga has yet to even have goku be defeted by frost, the Anime is the source of this data.

Comment: @Ryan An anime on the internet is not a professionally dubbed anime on TV, heh. I want to see it when it's on Toonami, with the voice actors of choice. Hopefully they also clean up the animation a bit before that point.

Comment: @axelrod It is on TV already, Japan TV (specifically the station FUJI TV). Your not wrong about the English Dubbed version, which does not exist, but the Subbed version is aired on TV before it can be recorded and Subbed on the internet. so technically, it is professionally Dubbed, by japaneese people in japaneese for Fuji TV.  that being said, some are waiting for DUB to watch, so seeing this question is an instant spoiler, which is probably why KP is respecting that and not revealing too much.

Comment: yea, seen it. it was a needle! And this race of Freeza is always the villain.